# At what time between 3 and 4 o'clock are the two hands coincident?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

In this question I found out the angle at which they meet by x/pi/6=(pi/4+x)/2pi where x came out to be pi/44.to find the time I divided pi by 44 by pi by 6 and multiplied by 60.my answer comes out to be 80/11.the answer is 160/11

Answer (score 1):

Since the two hands meet evenly spaced $11$ times in $12$ hours, the third time they meet since 12 o'clock is $36/11$ o'clock.  That's answer (D).